# Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, onedrive

I am trying to integrate the Onedrive SDK to the UWP Portion of my Xamarin App, However in the Upload and Download code, I get the following exception when ever the following lines are reached:

1. using (var stream = await sqliteStorageFileFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
2. using (IRandomAccessStream appFileStream = await appFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))

> Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   An Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))  mscorlib

Here is the relevant code snippnets:
UPLOAD:

```
       public async Task Upload(string filename)
    {
        await InitializeClient();
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        sqliteStorageFileFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

       try
        {
            using (var stream = await sqliteStorageFileFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("QW"); Debug.WriteLine("QW"); Debug.WriteLine("QW");
                var item = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(sqliteStorageFileFile.Name)
                            .Content.Request().PutAsync<Item>(stream);
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Id + "Id of item");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + e.Source);
        }

        return;
    }
```

DOWNLOAD:

```
  public async Task Download(string filename)
    {
        await InitializeClient();
        try
        {
            var filebuilder = OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filename);
            var backedUpFile = await filebuilder.Request().GetAsync();
            var fileStream = await filebuilder.Content.Request().GetAsync();
            //Byte Creation for fileStream
            byte[] fileBytes;
            IRandomAccessStream stream = fileStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
            using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
            {
                fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
            }

            IStorageFile appFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename,
           CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            using (IRandomAccessStream appFileStream = await appFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {

                using (IOutputStream outputStream = appFileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteBytes(fileBytes);
                        await writer.StoreAsync();
                        writer.DetachStream();
                    }
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("An Exception: " + e.Message + "  " + e.Source + "  ");
        }
    }
```

Please note the type of file I am trying to upload is a .db3 file (SQLite)

Creation of the Db and other relevant code is as follows:

```
 public class SQliteUWP : ISQlite
{
    public SQLiteConnection GetSqLiteConnection()
    {
        var sqliteFilename = "E-BusinessCardsSQLite.db3";
        var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        return connection;
    }
}

  public class EBusinessCardsSqlDatabase
{
    private SQLiteConnection _sqlDatabase;
    static object _locker = new object();

    public EBusinessCardsSqlDatabase()
    {
        _sqlDatabase = DependencyService.Get<ISQlite>().GetSqLiteConnection();
        _sqlDatabase.CreateTable<BusinessCard>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<BusinessCard> GetBusinessCards()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return (from bizCard in _sqlDatabase.Table<BusinessCard>() select bizCard).ToList();
        }
    }

    public BusinessCard GetBusinessCard(int cardId)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return _sqlDatabase.Table<BusinessCard>().FirstOrDefault(bizCard => bizCard.cardID == cardId);
        }
    }

    public int DeleteBusinessCard(int cardId)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return _sqlDatabase.Delete<BusinessCard>(cardId);
        }
    }

    public int SaveBusinessCard(BusinessCard card)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (card.cardID != 0)
            {
                _sqlDatabase.Update(card);
                return card.cardID;
            }
            else
            {
                return _sqlDatabase.Insert(card);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out file access permissions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Hi Roman, I can access the file and I get a storage file but when I try to open it for Reading into a Stream, with the API OpenAsync() or OpenStreamReadAsync() I get the error.

Comment: The code you've posted seems right. Could you please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? Besides, you may refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38217553/5506161). It works well in my side.

Comment: Hi Jay, I was researching on it and I was made aware of the fact that my sqlite db might still be open. I added more code to my question could you take a look at it?

Comment: Hi, It was a case of my db read and write i did not properly close it. Thanks Solved the problem. I needed to use using statement in read and writes.